# How do I convert an unsigned integer to an integer in Rust?

Tags: rust

So I'm trying to get a random number, but I'd rather not have it come back as uint instead of int... Not sure if this match is right, either, but the compiler doesn't get that far because it's never heard of this from_uint thing I'm trying to do:

```
fn get_random(max: &int) -> int {
        // Here we use * to dereference max
        // ...that is, we access the value at 
        // the pointer location rather than
        // trying to do math using the actual
        // pointer itself
        match int::from_uint(rand::random::<uint>() % *max + 1) {
                Some(n) => n,
                None => 0,
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`from_uint` is not in the namespace of `std::int`, but `std::num`: http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/num/fn.from_uint.html

*Original answer:*

Cast a `u32` to `int` with `as`. If you cast `uint` or `u64` to `int`, you risk overflowing into the negatives (assuming you are on 64 bit). From the docs:

> The size of a uint is equivalent to the size of a pointer on the particular architecture in question.

This works:

```
use std::rand;

fn main() { 
    let max = 42i; 
    println!("{}" , get_random(&max)); 
}

fn get_random(max: &int) -> int {
    (rand::random::<u32>() as int) % (*max + 1)
}
```

Comment: I like your answer and it works, but I'm hoping someone will come along to explain why the from_thing() functions don't seem to be working the way I thought they would.

Comment: is there something that returns an Option<int> so you can handle overflow?

Comment: `from_uint` removed from `std::num`

Comment: What you do here is quite dangerous, you should know that your function get_random does not create a valid random distribution. Do not use this for security related applications!

For a good solution, see: http://doc.rust-lang.org/num/rand/index.html